# Can't locate keytouch

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install keytouch to get my keyboard special keys, but I'm getting

```
    E: Unable to locate package keytouch
```

Comment: What command did you use to try and install it?

Comment: Ubuntu Packages (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=keytouch) says that the exact package is only for lucid, which has support ending soon (if it hasn't already ended)

Comment: ethan: thanks!!!!

Any ideas if there's some keyboard utility for 14.04?

Comment: @AgustinSantiago: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the below answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `keytouch` is not in the Utopic repositories, as stated by @ethanbmnz in comments. To install `keytouch`, you can either install the `deb` package for `keytouch` (with `sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE.deb`, where PACKAGE.deb is the filename of the package) or compile it from source then install it.

Source and Debian packages can be found at http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/dl-keytouch.php. It appears the packaged version is of an older version, so if there's anything present in the newer versions of `keytouch` that you need, I would recommend that you compile it from source.